# C++ STL map in shared memory

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, shared-memory

i need to place a STL map in shared memory. Also have multiple process access that map. Any pointers to how it is done ?

I have checked this link. But need a more simpler method. 
[Map in Shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842082/map-in-shared-memory)

Comment: Use boost, as this is a bit of a pain to achieve. Or are you constrained by what libraries you can use?

Comment: Don't. It's unlikely that your STL implementation's map is binary-stable.

Comment: @BillyONeal, assuming you're referring to ABI stability, and even assuming that's true, surely if all processes use the same compiler version that isn't a problem? (There are other problems in getting this  to work, but I don't think that's one of them!)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: In practice having everyone use the same compiler version turns out to be a big hurdle for people :)

Comment: @BillyONea, one reason why the two major non-Microsoft std::lib implementations _do_ have stable ABIs :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes and no. See: vstring:)

Comment: @BillyONeal, do you mean `std::string`? We still provide the old version too, so it's still ABI backward compatible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102697/discussion-between-billy-oneal-and-jonathan-wakely).

Comment: thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work you need to use a custom allocator that will allocate from the shared memory region, so that the map nodes are all in shared memory, and so that the `pointer` type of the allocator is not just a raw pointer but can refer to the shared memory region when it is mapped to different addresses in different processes.

You also need your `std::map` implementation to correctly use the allocator's `pointer` type *everywhere* it needs to use a pointer, and this [isn't guaranteed by the standard](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2261).

The simplest way to do this currently is to use Boost.Interprocess which provides a nice API for shared memory and also provides allocators and containers that work correctly with it.